# If Darth Vader is more machine than man, wouldn't he have significantly less midichlorians?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, midichlorians

Something that occurred to me...

If midichlorians are just cells living inside a living host, and total number of midichlorians determines just how powerful you are in the force, wouldn't removing a substantial amount of blood in the form of robotic appendages significantly reduce the midichlorian count, thereby making you much less powerful?

Seems like Darth Vader should have lost quite a bit of his force powers when he got robotic legs and arms.

Comment: Yoda is pretty small, yet he doesn't seem to lack midichlorians because of that. I don't this is that simple.

Comment: No, because his first appearance as a machine occurred before midichlorians were part of the franchise, so when the retcon demons came along, they decided he would be grandfathered in